# Need offline iOS GPS app for Southeast Asia

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, iphone, gps

Looking for recommendations for a good offline GPS tracker for SE Asia (Singapore, Cambodia, and Thailand, specifically). I was looking at [Gaia GPS](http://www.gaiagps.com/), but I can't quite tell from their site if they support anything outside of the US and Canada.

The idea is that I want to have GPS tracks of my wanderings so I can later sync them up with the photos I take (it'll make it a lot easier to figure out what I'm looking at in my pictures when I go to work with them months after I get back). I'll be in areas with terrible cell reception, so ability to track solely on GPS is a must - otherwise I'd just be using RunKeeper.

I'm planning to take my 3GS just because it'll be easier to get a SIM card, so whatever it is has to support the 3GS. This should be mostly fine since the 3GS runs iOS 6, but figured it was worth a mention.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaia GPS has many map sources that cover SE Asia. I am one of the developers, and you can email support@gaiagps.com if you have any questions.

Comment: Are your maps offline too?

Comment: Yeah, they definitely had the offline functionality I was looking for, I was mostly unable to tell if they covered international destinations.

Andrew, thank you!